# How append works in hdfs? Where the newly created instance of file is placed?

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, apache-hadoop

I'm a Newbie to Hadoop!

By web search and after going through hadoop guides, it is clear that hdfs doesn't allow us to edit the file but to append some data to existing file, it will be creating a new instance temporarily and append the new data to it.

That being said,

1.would like to know whether the *new file* or *temp file* is created in the *same block* or in a *different block*?

2.What will happen if the revised file **exceeds** the previous  allocated block size?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/07/file-appends-in-hdfs/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162943/how-does-hdfs-with-append-works